# Write data to file at certain position

Tags: objective-c, file

I have a file with content like this:

```
Name:      Block:      Mark:
Description:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus quis massa magna. Nunc consectetur dignissim ligula. Suspendisse eu arcu eu.
Date:
```

Summarazing, i need to search the character ':' in the file and then write the consecuent string. In C/C++ this is easy.

In objective-C i read you can read all the file and store each line as a string an save it in a NSMutableArray and then search the key-character ':' a concatenate the consecuent solution string. At the end you only need to rewrite all the file.

That would work fine if the file is small but if you work with a big file, Is it posible to search into the content of a file and then write after without extracting all the content.